# Saving steps in Euclidean division algorithm

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I am just beginning programming and for my first project, I decided to write a program for finding the greatest common divisor using the Euclidean division algorithm in c.

Now though, I want to extend the problem to save the intermittent quotients, remainders, dividends and divisors so that I can use them.

My thought was that I could add something to the inner loop that would put each of the four variables into one row of the array and then start a new row for the next iteration of the loop.

Here's what I have so far.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    NSAutoreleasePool * pool =[[NSAutoreleasePool alloc]init];
    NSMutableArray * numberSaver=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSNumber * q;
    NSNumber * end;
    NSNumber * or;
    NSNumber * rem;

    int a,b, divisor, dividend, quotient, remainder, temp, gcd, row;

    //get the two numbers
    NSLog(@"of which 2 numbers whould you like the GCD?");
    scanf("%u%u", &a,&b);

    //make the bigger number the dividend, smaller divisor

    if (a>b) {
        dividend=a;
        divisor=b;
    } else {
        dividend=b;
        divisor=a;
    }

    remainder=1;
    row=0;
    while (remainder !=0) {

        quotient=1;
        temp=divisor;

        while (temp<dividend) {
            temp+=divisor;
            ++quotient;
        }
        q=[NSNumber numberWithInt:quotient];
        end=[NSNumber numberWithInt: dividend];
        or=[NSNumber numberWithInt: divisor];
        //set NSNumber objects q, end, or to the integer values at quotient dividend and divisor

        gcd=divisor;
        //This is so that we can save divisor to be the GCD and not change it to 0 before it is printed
        remainder=quotient*divisor - dividend;
        rem=[NSNumber numberWithInt:remainder];
        //point to the remainder as an object

        dividend= divisor;
        divisor= remainder;
        //Get dividend and divisor ready for the next loop

        //I'd like to start adding the newly created NSNumbers to  numberSaver here
        [numberSaver addObject:quotient atIndex:row:0];
    }
    NSLog(@"gcd= %u",gcd);

    [pool drain] ;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest creating a mutable dictionary with each iteration of the loop and, after adding all the numbers to that, put it into the "master" array:

```
while (remainder !=0) {

    // Each time through the loop, a new dictionary is created and put
    // into iterationDict; you can then add objects to it.
    NSMutableDictionary * iterationDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

    // ...

    q=[NSNumber numberWithInt:quotient];
    end=[NSNumber numberWithInt: dividend];
    or=[NSNumber numberWithInt: divisor];

    [iterationDict setObject:q forKey:@"quotient"];
    [iterationDict setObject:end forKey:@"dividend"];
    [iterationDict setObject:or forKey:@"divisor"];

    // etc.
    [numberSaver addObject:iterationDict];
}
```

Storing these things in a dictionary rather than an array means that you don't have to remember the *order* in which you added them (`divisor` before `dividend`, e..g). Instead, you access them by the key. Later, you can get the values for any given iteration out of the array:

```
NSUInteger iteration = 3;
NSNumber * quotient = [[numberSaver objectAtIndex:iteration] objectForKey:@"quotient"];
```

Please comment if any of this needs explication.

Comment: Thanks that worked well. If I am writing more code, how can I access the last iteration without knowing how many iterations have been completed?

Comment: @User: the last object in the array is at `num_objects_in_array - 1`, so you would do: `[numberSaver objectAtIndex:[numbersaver count] - 1]`